# SharePoint 2013

Tags: database, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can I retrieve data from content database in SharePoint 2013? I need only read from the database. I need also to read metadata as well. I was wondering if anybody could explain it and give me even a tutorial links for that. I am a newbie in SharePoint, I read different articles but I cannot find the information that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the first rules of SharePoint that you learn when you start diving in to the product is that you shouldn't ever touch the SharePoint database.

Also, Reading from the SharePoint databases programmatically, or manually, can cause unexpected locking within Microsoft SQL Server which can adversely affect performance.

So you should use sharepoint object model, rest Apis to query data.

Also check:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_farnhill/archive/2013/12/04/directly-querying-sharepoint-databases.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read this article before but the thing is that I don't know how to use sharepoint object model or REST API to query data. Do you know any useful tutorial for that?

Comment: You can start with following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538251(v=office.14).aspx